# Fetching data through Vector

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee

I am trying to fetch data from 1 single table having 22 rows and 20 columns (lets say reference_table) of database and compare it's values as a refernce with few elements of other 16 tables(holding the present state of data of some environment).

I am using vector to store the data of REFERENCE_TABLE,each row as a object of some class "X",and use individual data through "vector.get(0).getvalue()".

[getValue() is method of class "X" having column_names as variables ]

So I am fetching reference_values only once into vector at the initial phase of application and then using it in different methods through out the application , rather than fetching the data from database everytime.

So my dilema is:

Whether using data from vector(by passing it to different methods)  is efficient or fetching data from database table ?

I WANT THE EXECUTION TIME OF THE APPLICATION TO BE THE MINIMUM.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Benchmark, do some measurement with both variants, consider network latency to DB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comprehension with java web application, it is better to leave data in database as this will comply with model/control separation, or Data/business-logic separation.

But actually, to achieve this separation will result in a bad application performance problem, that each time you need data, you have to get a connection with database.  Thus many developer like to control database themselves, which might have transaction consistency problems.

Hence generally speaking, according to the transaction consistency principle, you should use a transaction manager, or control transaction all by yourself very carefully.

Also, you need to measure the connection time and some other metrix to ensure the performance of your web application. but honestly, I think Java EE application's performance is very satisfactory compared with `Python` or `php`

Comment: Thankx soo much.i am trying context Listner for fetching the value  only once,but i couldn't find web.xml to do the respective mapping.There is no web.xml file in netbeans 7.2.1. What to do now?

Comment: @Shashank just copy one from other project, it is a generic file